# ReactJS - How append styles from parent to child?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I created component and style it (using sass):

```
const WidgetCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={style["widget-card"]}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now I using this component in my widget:

```
const TasksWidget = () => {
  return (
    <WidgetCard>
      <p>SOME AWESOME CONTENT</p>
    </WidgetCard>
  )
}
```

But now, I'm need append/change some styles of `WidgetCard` component from my `TaskWidget` (for example width).

How I can implement this with react css modules?

Comment: Why not to reuse the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are speaking of changing the inner component by its parent (high order component) you can just inject inline styles from TasksWidget into WidgetCard, and put the changing capability to it, for example:

```
const TasksWidget = () => {
  const styleToInject = { width: 30rem }
  return (
    <WidgetCard styles={styleToInject}>
      <p>SOME AWESOME CONTENT</p>
    </WidgetCard>
  )
}
```

and then configure to child to have the capability to recieve the style prop:

```
const WidgetCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={props.styles ? props.styles : null } className={style["widget-card"]}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Better practice is to define expected props with PropTypes and even so, put default values to non required fields (style in our case:

```
WidgetCard.propTypes = {
    childre: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    styles: PropTypes.obj
}

WidgetCard.defaultProps = {
    styles: null
}
```

so the final WidgetCard component will look like

```
const WidgetCard = ({ children, styles }) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles} className={style["widget-card"]}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

checkout the PropTypes library:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: Is there a better way if there are several places in the component that need to be styled?  Or do separate props to each place?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your style/class name/width as a prop from the parent and use it in child

```
const TasksWidget = () => {
  return (
    <WidgetCard style={{width: '40px'}} className="new-width" width="40px">
      <p>SOME AWESOME CONTENT</p>
    </WidgetCard>
  )
}
```

```
const WidgetCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`${style["widget-card"]} ${props.className}`} 
    style={...props.style, width: props.width}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use css `inherit`, no?
Because you know, whats better at doing css than css.
if you want the text color to inherit for example:

```
// widget card css
.widget-card { color: transparent }

// text widget css
.text-widget { color: inherit; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit